# Get Internal Name of Item using CSOM in Powershell 2013 SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

```
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$list=$web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName);
        $qry=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
            $items=$list.GetItems($qry)
            $context.Load($items)
            $context.ExecuteQuery() 

            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$baklist=$web.Lists.GetByTitle($backupListname);

            Write-Host "before foreach" $items.Count
            foreach($item in $items)
            {
            Write-Host "inside foreach InternalName" $item.get_internalName()

            $count=$item.FieldValues.Values
     [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation]$itemCreateInfo = New-Object          
           Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation;
              [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem]$backupItem = $baklist.AddItem($itemCreateInfo);

             $backupItem["Title"]=$item["Title"]
            ***in above line i have take "Title" as internal name***
              ***instead of title how to get internal name here*,**
         ***i had tried below line but its not working for me***
              ***$backupItem.InternalName=$item.InternalName***
             $backupItem.Update()
            }
```

**inabove code:-**
$backupItem["Title"]=$item["Title"]
                ***in above line i have take "Title" as internal name***
                  ***instead of title how to get internal name here*,**
             ***i had tried below line but its not working for me***
                  ***$backupItem.InternalName=$item.InternalName***